# Unable to pass the uploaded file name into the angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

We are working on form where user can upload 4 different photos. when i click choose file, it is calling to upload.php file and storing that file into uploadfiles directory.

but after file is uploaded unable to passing that particular file name to the angularjs.

Here is the UI Code

```
<head>  
    <script src="add-customer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-file-upload.js"> </script>
</head>
<body data-ng-cloak data-ng-app="AddCustomerApp" data-ng-controller="AddCustomerController as parentCtrl">
    <section id="container">
        <section id="main-content">
            <section class="wrapper">
                <div class="row mt">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-panel">
                            <h4 class="mb">Add Customer</h4>
                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="AddCustomerForm" name="AddCustomerForm" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="" data-ng-submit="AddCustomerData(AddCustomer)">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" required placeholder="First Name" autofocus data-ng-model="AddCustomer.firstname">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div controller="ChildController as childCtrl">
                                        <div class="form-group" >
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <label for="photo">Aadhaar Front</label>
                                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="adarfront" name="adarfront" required placeholder="Aadhaar Front" data-ng-model="AddCustomer.adarfront" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <label for="photo">Aadhaar Back</label>
                                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="adarback" name="adarback" required placeholder="Aadhaar Back" data-ng-model="AddCustomer.adarback" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <label for="photo">Other ID Photo Front</label>
                                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="otheridfront" name="otheridfront" required placeholder="Other ID Photo Front" data-ng-model="AddCustomer.otheridfront" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <label for="photo">Other ID Photo Back</label>
                                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="otheridback" name="otheridback" required placeholder="Other ID Photo Back" data-ng-model="AddCustomer.otheridback" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme" data-ng-disabled="AddCustomerForm.$invalid">Add</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
</body>
```

Here is the AngularJs Code

```
var AddCustomer = angular.module("AddCustomerApp", ['angularFileUpload','ui.bootstrap'])
AddCustomer.controller("AddCustomerController", function ($scope, $timeout, $http, jsonFilter)
{       
    $scope.PersonalDetails = true;  
    var logResult = function (data, status, headers, config)
    {
        return data;
    };  

$scope.AddCustomerData = function (AddCustomer)
    {       
    if($scope.AddCustomer.firstname==undefined || $scope.AddCustomer.adarfront==undefined || $scope.AddCustomer.adarback==undefined || $scope.AddCustomer.otheridfront==undefined || $scope.AddCustomer.otheridback==undefined)
        {
                alert("All fields are mendatory");
                $scope.PersonalDetails = true;
                $scope.WarningAlert = data;
        }
    else
        {
            $http.post('add-customer-process.php',{'firstname':$scope.AddCustomer.firstname,'adarfront':$scope.AddCustomer.adarfront,'adarback':$scope.AddCustomer.adarback,'otheridfront':$scope.AddCustomer.otheridfront,'otheridback':$scope.AddCustomer.otheridback})
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config)
            {
                if(data=="Success")
                {
                $scope.PersonalDetails = true;
                $scope.SuccessAlert = "Data added successfully";
                $scope.AddCustomer = {};
                $scope.AddCustomerForm.$setPristine();
                $scope.AddCustomerForm.$setUntouched();
                }               
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config)
            {
                $scope.WarningAlert = logResult(data, status, headers, config);
            });
        }   
        $scope.switchBool = function (value) {
        $scope[value] = !$scope[value];
        };
    };
});

AddCustomer.controller('ChildController',function ($scope, $http, $upload)
{
    $scope.parentCtrl.childCtrl = $scope.childCtrl;
    $scope.onFileSelect = function($files)
        {   
                $scope.message = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++)
                 {
                    var file = $files[i];
                    console.log(file);
                    $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
                        url: 'upload.php',
                        method: 'POST',
                        file: file
                    }).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config)
                     {
                        $scope.message = data;
                        $scope.message=$scope.message.replace('\"', '');
                        $scope.childCtrl.message=$scope.message.replace('\"', '');  
                     })
                    .error(function(data, status) 
                     {
                         $scope.message = data;
                     });
                }
            };      
});
```

kindly help Us. I'm newbie to AngularJS. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Why not set your php file to return with the filename stored?

Comment: this is my upload.php code<?php
 $target_dir = "uploadfiles/";
 $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
 $result = array("filename" => $_FILES["file"]);
 $filename = $result['filename']['name'];
 echo json_encode($filename);
?>

Comment: how to pass that each file name in to ngmodel?

Comment: Do you get the file name from .success((function(data, status, headers, config) { ...?

Comment: No sir, that is the problem. how to pass the file name to particular ng-model while uploading the file?

Comment: generally you have 2 choices, 1. get file from server as I mentionned before, need just to send back the filename, 2. get file name before uploading, could be in the file object, console.log(file); shouldbe file.fileName

Comment: As you said, i am sending back the file name to ng-model. while submitting it is coming undefined.

Comment: What do you got if you console log the response from server? in success; console.log(data);